# Account detail Save and Multiple Callouts in lightning experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

My use case goes like this. I have about 70-80 fields on my Account detail page broken down into 7 or 8 sections. Now, if I click edit and change some of these values and hit Save, I need to be able to call different webservices with these changed values (only if they have changed) based on which values has changed - for ex. an email change would invoke a profile webservice as compared a balance field which would invoke payment webservice as an example.

I don't think I can override my Save action in LE, so I guess the only way is for to write a trigger and compare the old and new and if they have changed, and based on which values have changed, make the required (@future) callouts to the required webservice. Is that the only way or are there any alternatives that I'm missing?

My key issue/ question is if I have to rollback my Salesforce changes based on the response (if it failed for some reason), I will be unable to do it with this pattern unless of course I roll out my own Lightning component and not use the OOTB Account details page which I'm not keen on doing.

Looking for some guidance/best ways of doing this.

Comment: If you want to stick to OOTB components, they are like black boxes in a sense that you won't be able to listen to or handle any changes or events. You must resort to triggers in that case, I am afraid. If you end up considering custom route, this should get you started: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have very few options since you dont want to override save and go the custom  component route.

Even with trigger since you need to do a future callout you have no control on when the response will come back and incase of errors its a separate transaction altogether.

You could end up showing a error message to user at a later point when the response comes back and store it in a field if he happens to come back to the same record.

Comment: do you know how can I override the Save capability in LE when the user clicks and edits the fields.